# How to drop duplicate data with different column names in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unique, drop-duplicates

I have a  DataFrame  with columns with duplicate data with different names:

```
In[1]: df
Out[1]: 
  X1   X2  Y1   Y2
 0.0  0.0  6.0  6.0
 3.0  3.0  7.1  7.1
 7.6  7.6  1.2  1.2
```

I know .drop(columns = ) exists but is there a way more efficient way to drop these without having to list down the column names? or not.. please let me know as i can just use .drop()

Answer (score 7):

We can use [**`np.unique`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) over axis 1. Unfortunately, there's no pandas built-in function to drop duplicate columns.

[**`df.drop_duplicates`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) only removes duplicate rows.

> Return DataFrame with duplicate rows removed.

We can create a function around `np.unique` to drop duplicate columns.

```
def drop_duplicate_cols(df):
    uniq, idxs = np.unique(df, return_index=True, axis=1)
    return pd.DataFrame(uniq, index=df.index, columns=df.columns[idxs])

drop_duplicate_cols(X)
    X1   Y1
0  0.0  6.0
1  3.0  7.1
2  7.6  1.2
```

[<kbd>Online Demo</kbd>](https://replit.com/@Ch3seR/tobool#main.py)

> **NB:** [**`np.unique`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) docs:
>
> > Returns the sorted unique elements of an array.
>
> **Workaround:** To retain the original order, sort the `idxs`.

---

Using `.T` on dataframe having multiple `dtypes` is going to mess with your actual `dtypes`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1], 'B': ['a', 'b'], 'C': [0, 1], 'D':[2.1, 3.1]})
df.dtypes
A      int64
B     object
C      int64
D    float64
dtype: object

df.T.T.dtypes
A    object
B    object
C    object
D    object
dtype: object
# To get back original `dtypes` we can use `.astype`
df.T.T.astype(df.dtypes).dtypes
A      int64
B     object
C      int64
D    float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: This should be  faster as it uses numpy functions over numpy array without having to transform the shape. +1

Comment: @anky Thank you :D I believe `.T` has a certain overhead. timeit over OP;s data `np.unique` is almost 8X faster. But `np.unique` doesn't scale well I guess I read that somewhere.

Comment: @anky One more major flaw is when a df has multiple types `.T` would change dtypes too.

Comment: Not a flaw but a caveat to know.

Comment: Apologies I forgot to mention this however my data has another column with no duplicates e.g. X1 X2 Y1 Y2 Z. I noticed using this code dropped Z column completely. how do I code everything with this column as an exception?

Comment: @ahnnni Post the data with `Z` column, please. But the solution should work. Please post the data so I can inspect what's going on.

Comment: @ahnnni [Online demo](https://replit.com/@Ch3seR/tobool#main.py) working as expected.

Answer (score 6):

You could transpose with `T` and `drop_duplicates` then transpose back:

```
>>> df.T.drop_duplicates().T
    X1   Y1
0  0.0  6.0
1  3.0  7.1
2  7.6  1.2
>>>
```

Or with `loc` and `duplicated`:

```
>>> df.loc[:, df.T.duplicated(keep='last')]
    X1   Y1
0  0.0  6.0
1  3.0  7.1
2  7.6  1.2
>>>
```

Comment: Apologies I forgot to mention this however my data has another column with no duplicates e.g. X1 X2 Y1 Y2 Z. I noticed using this code dropped Z column completely. how do I code everything with this column as an exception?

Comment: @ahnnni Use the first solution then.

Comment: @ahnnni The first solution should work